# VMware Clarity wizard with sub pages (e.g., 3a, 3b, etc)

Tags: vmware-clarity

I've read through the documentation at https://v2.clarity.design/wizards and tried searching through the code on github, but haven't figured out how to create a wizard with sub or child pages.

What I'd like to do is have a wizard with steps like this:

```
1. Step 1
2. Step 2 [next goes directly to step 3a]
3. Contains Sub Steps
3a. sub step 1
3b. sub step 2
4. Step 4
```

What I want to do is dynamically generate the sub steps based on an array that will have an undetermined number of objects until Step 1 is complete. I would prefer not to have steps 1-15 or a single page with multiple forms if I can avoid it.

I've tried nesting `<clr-wizard-page>` blocks but that doesn't work. I've search for page groups, sub pages, sub steps, child pages, child steps, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me to some documentation or give me some search terms?

I really appreciate any help!